# passing parameters to cwl from snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to execute some cwl pipelines using snakemake. I need to pass parameters to cwltool, which snakemake is using to execute the pipeline.

cwltool has a number of options. Currently, when snakemake calls it, the only option that I can figure out how to pass is --singularity, and that is easy, because if you call snakemake with the --use-singularity flag, it automatically inserts it into the call to cwltool.

```
snakemake --jobs 999 --printshellcmds --rerun-incomplete --use-singularity 
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 999
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       align
        1

[Tue Aug 11 06:55:18 2020]
rule align:
    input: /project/uoa00571/projects/rapidAutopsy/data/raw/dna_batch2/BA1_1.fastq.gz, /nesi/project/uoa00571/projects/rapidAutopsy/data/raw/dna_batch2/BA1_2.fastq.gz
    output: /nobackup/uoa00571/data/intermediate/rapidAutopsy/BA1.unaligned.bam
    jobid: 0
    threads: 8

cwltool --singularity file:/project/uoa00571/projects/rapidAutopsy/src/gridss/gridssAlignment.cwl /tmp/tmpfgsz5uvr
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to add additional arguments to the cwltool call. When snakemake calls the cwl tool, it doesn't appear to pass on the working directory, so if I do :

```
snakemake --jobs 999 --printshellcmds   --rerun-incomplete  --use-singularity --directory "/nesi/nobackup/uoa00571/data/intermediate/rapidAutopsy/"
```

instead of landing intermediate files in the specified directory, singularity appears to be binding a directory in the /tmp directory for the intermediate files, which on the system I am working on, is not big enough, resulting in a disk quota exceeded error.

```
singularity \
    --quiet \
    exec \
    --contain \
    --pid \
    --ipc \
    --home \
    /tmp/xq5co13r:/sSyVnR \
    --bind \
    /tmp/vbjabhqx:/tmp:rw \
```

Or at least, that's what I think is happening. If I run the cwl pipeline using cwltool, I can add in the option --cacheDir and the pipeline will run to completion, so I'd like to be able to pass that from snakemake to the cwltool call, if that's possible?

Comment: Have you looked into [`--singularity-args`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#SINGULARITY)?

Comment: --singularity-args works when you're passing singularity arguments to the workflow. To the best of my understanding, it doesn't get customized for each part of the workflow. Also, --singularity-args goes into the singularity command  that is created for  the sbatch script, there's no way that I can see to pass arguments from --singularity-args and put them into the header of the sbatch script that is created to submit a job to slurm.